# JavaScript displaying scores & messages based on different conditions

Tags: javascript

JavaScript Nesting if condition.

The JS code is asking the user 2 questions and each question got 4 options to be chosen as an answer, each answer got a specific value and if the user's score will be 6 and more each chosen answeres that got the value 4 will get addiitonal comment and I tried to implement it but I didn't manage it.

Just an example:

Example:

Question 01: Do you like chocolate? Answer: Yes a lot.

Question 02: Do you prefer chocolate cake or carrot cake? Answer: Both.

First answer got the value 4 and second 2, so in total it's got 6 points.

```
var health = 'Very Healthy';
var average = 'Neither Healthy nor unhealthy';
var unhealthy = 'Unhealthy';
```

Any suggestions for the right solution?

I saved my newest idea in the following fiddle link => http://jsfiddle.net/Hf68f/

Comment: In GetAdditionalComment2 there is an undefined variable called scoreCake.

Comment: @Dan Iveson, yes I did a mistake by accident, okay I have done the correction and still the code is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your last two functions (`getAdditionalComment1` and `getAdditionalComment2`), you have a syntax error. You are using `()` instead of `{}` to enclose the function. It should look like

```
function getAdditionalComment1(score, scoreChoco)
{ // Changed here
    if(score >=6){
        if (scoreChoco == 4)
        return additionalCommentYesAlot;
        else
        return "";
    }

} // And here
function getAdditionalComment2(score, scoreCake)
{ // And here
    if(score >=6){
        if (scoreCake == 4)
        return addionalCommentChocolate;
        else
        return "";
    }

} // And here
```

Once the syntax error is resolved, the code runs fine in my testing.

Comment: thank you, I did really silly mistakes, I have created a new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cQJHq/ , well it is not really working the way how I wish to, it supposed to add additional comments apart from unhealthy, so it's not doing it.

Comment: Those two functions aren't being called anywhere in your fiddle. And once you add that, you should be able to add your additional comments to your element pretty easily.

Comment: So I should call them in function getTotal() maybe.

Comment: Also the result of getComment is not displayed anywhere.

Comment: Yeah, add a call to each in get total, and append them to your output. You can go from there. Looks like `getAdditionalComment2` also has a misspelling in the variable name `additionalCommentChocolate`. @DanIveson It is displayed in the fiddle fine. Not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: @Ktash I was still on the old fiddle.

Comment: Ohh..Too many spelling mistakes I did, Okay, I will try now again give me 2 min, I am kind of new to these sort of stuff...

Comment: @Ktash, okay I tried, but it didn't work, this is my newest fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/4Wwry/

Comment: @Acemi Two small things to fix, and you should have it. First you'll want to fix the parameters being passed into the functions. Right now you're passing in `score, scoreChoco`, but you'll actually want to use `totalScore, getScoreChoco()` instead (and same for cake). Second, in the `.innerHTML = ` parts for those additional comments, you'll want to do a `+=` which will add it to the end instead of overriding it like `=` will.

Comment: @Ktash, l am a nerd looking bimbo, l hope l will be able to fix it, give me 2 min please.

Comment: @Ktash, I tried to improve it, but it still not working, okay again this is now the newest fiddle ===> http://jsfiddle.net/Qqa7t/

Comment: @Acemi Close, but [try this one](http://jsfiddle.net/erKdm/). I moved the comments out into variables to make it a bit clearer what is going on. Hopefully that helps :)

Comment: @Ktash, OMG OMG, that's perfect, thank you very very very much :) you are my favourite user :D

Answer (score 1):

I have cleaned your code, making it easy to add new questions, avoiding almost duplicate functions and using code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22578102/1529630) to choose messages:

```
var numericalValues = {
    Alot: 4,
    NotMuch: 2,
    NoSometimes: 3,
    Hate: 0,
    Chocolate: 4,
    Carrot: 0,
    Both: 2,
    None: 0
};

function getScore(name) {
    var form = document.forms["form"],
        els = form.elements[name];
    for(var i=0; i<els.length; i++)
        if(els[i].checked)
            return numericalValues[els[i].value];
}

var names = ['cake', 'choco'];

function getTotal() {
    var scores = [], totalScore = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<names.length; ++i)
        totalScore += scores[names[i]] = getScore(names[i]);
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 
        getComment(totalScore)
        + '. '+
        getAdditionalComment(scores);
}

var comments = [
    [0, 'Very Healthy'],                  /* For 0,1,2        */
    [3, 'Neither Healthy nor unhealthy'], /* For 3,4,5,6      */
    [7, 'Unhealthy']                      /* For 7...Infinity */
],
additionalComments = {
    choco: [
        [4, 'you eat too much chocolate']/*,
        [5, void 0] // Not needed since 4 is maximum */
    ],
    cake: [
        [4, 'you have to start a diet']/*,
        [5, void 0] // Not needed since 4 is maximum */
    ]
};
function getValueInRange(arr, n, from, to) {
    return (function main(from, to){
        if(from>=to) return void 0;
        var mid = Math.floor((from+to)/2);
        if(arr[mid][0] > n) return main(from, mid);
        if(arr[mid][0] < n && mid > from) return main(mid, to);
        return arr[mid][1];
    })(from===void 0 ? 0 : from, to===void 0 ? arr.length : to);
}
function getComment(score) {
    return getValueInRange(comments, score);
}
function getAdditionalComment(scores) {
    var arr = [];
    for(var i=0, l=names.length; i<l; ++i) {
        var txt = getValueInRange(
            additionalComments[names[i]],
            scores[names[i]]
        );
        if(txt) arr.push(txt);
    }
    return arr.join(', ');
}

document.getElementById('calculate').onclick=getTotal;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cQJHq/3/)

Comment: @Acemi Not at all :) Some things may be advanced, but you could use some things not much different than your code, such as `getScore(name)` instead of almost duplicate `getScoreChoco()` and `getScoreCake()`